# Pulling out strings of values sequentially from a list of values

Tags: r, arrays, automation

I'm trying to write an R program that will do data analysis for our lab but i'm struggling a bit.
The analysis is based on machines that will run one sample multiple times. Every such cycle is called a heating cycle. We can get our software to export a word document that contains data tables where every data table represent some event that occurred during one of the heating cycles.
These experiments are always ran in triplicates, so you end up with a couple of word documents each with a couple of tables. The goal is to calculate the means from table 1 from doc1, doc2, and docc3, and so forth per table.

This is easy enough to code and I have a program for my own samples, since a certain sample will always be linked to a known amount of tables.

This is where it gets difficult though: i want to write a program that will run through R shiny where people can tell R how many tables each document has and the code works for any amount of tables. It's basically a generalized version of the code I already wrote for my samples.
On top of this, the data is a mess so it needs to be cleaned up.

This is where i'm stuck atm:

```
# Function to clean and convert a single value
clean_and_convert <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("[°C]", "", x)
  x <- gsub("[J/g]", "", x)
  x <- gsub(",", ".", x)
  return(as.numeric(x))
}

# Function to extract values from a specified row of a table and apply clean_and_convert
extract_values <- function(table, row_index) {
  # Convert to data frame if the table is not already
  table_df <- as.data.frame(table)
  
  # Remove the first column
  table_df <- table_df[, -1, drop = FALSE]
  
  # Extract cleaned values from the second row
  values <- table_df[row_index, , drop = FALSE]
  
  # Apply clean_and_convert to each value
  cleaned_values <- lapply(values, clean_and_convert)
  
  # Return the vector
  return(unlist(cleaned_values))
}

# Function to extract tables from a Word document
extract_tables <- function(doc) {
  tables <- docxtractr::docx_extract_all_tbls(doc)
  return(tables)
}

# Function to extract and name vectors based on user input
extract_and_name_vectors <- function(tables, num_tables, variable_prefix, doc_index) {
  user_vectors <- list()
  
  # Extract and name vectors for each table
  for (i in seq_len(num_tables)) {
    # Extract rows based on user input
    extracted_rows <- tables[[i]][seq_len(num_tables), ]
    
    # Clean and convert the values
    cleaned_values <- lapply(extracted_rows, clean_and_convert)
    
    # Create vector names based on user input variable prefix
    vector_names <- paste0(variable_prefix, seq_len(ncol(extracted_rows)), "doc", doc_index)
    
    # Assign the cleaned values to named vectors
    user_vectors[[paste0("table", i, variable_prefix, "doc", doc_index)]] <- setNames(
      unlist(cleaned_values), vector_names
    )
  }
  
  return(user_vectors)
}

# Extract tables and create separate lists for each document
tables_doc1 <- lapply(extract_tables(doc1), function(table) extract_values(table, 2))
tables_doc2 <- lapply(extract_tables(doc2), function(table) extract_values(table, 2))
tables_doc3 <- lapply(extract_tables(doc3), function(table) extract_values(table, 2))
```

This results in three lists of values tables_doc1, tables_doc2, and tables_doc3 as you can see.

Now, from each of these tables, I want to extract the vectors containing the actual data per table.
The variable names however, are tricky.
For the first X vectors from doc1 that are extracted, where X is a user defined input, I want the variable name to be HC1doc1. For the Y next vectors that are extracted, it should be HC2doc1, and so forth. This should be repeated for the 3 tables.

I tried to get chatGPT to help me but it keeps coming up with ways to make more lists of vectors but I want the data is individual variables.

```
-some variable- <- as.numeric(tables_doc1[[1]])
```

does the trick but it needs to be a sequence and not require manual input, this kind of code wouldn't be applicable on documents with different amounts of tables.

I hope I was even somewhat clear in my question :). I'm a bit new at this so please go slow.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: *"export a word document that contains data tables"* to me sounds like two things: (1) the `.NORM` file format (see https://xkcd.com/2116/), and (2) a horrible idea. Is there anyway to encourage the software to output results in a less horrible way?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Tom Konings! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (good start here); sample representative data, perhaps pick one such docx and run `obj <- docx_extract_all_tbls(.); dput(obj)`; and your expected output given that sample data. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: (For clarity, please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(obj)` into a [code block]. Thanks!)